# Server-Client using UDP

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp

I am a new to Java socket programming, so please pardon me if I've asked something very basic and stupid.I created a server-client program using Java sockets(UDP).The client asks for a quote whenever it communicates to the Server, and the server sends a quote to the client.The problem is that the client is not receiving the quote,despite the server sending it.Also, the server continues to serve the same client for an infinite no. of times(I understand that this might be because of the while loop).Is there any way that the server  serves each client once per request?Here is my serve class.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Random;

public class Server {
static String quote1="Last words are for fools who did not speak enough.";
static String quote2="When I die bury me with face down so that the whole   World can kiss my ass.";
static String quote3="The real enemy in a war is war itself.";
static String quote4="Whoever saves a life,save the World entire.";
static String quote5="Power is when we've every justification to kill,and we don't.";

static String[] quotes={quote1,quote2,quote3,quote4,quote5};

static byte[] sendData;
static byte[] receiveData;

public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
{
 sendData=new byte[1024];
 receiveData=new byte[1024];
Random rand=new Random();
String str;

    if(args.length==0)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the port number in the arguements");
    }
    else
    {DatagramSocket socket=new DatagramSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
        while(true)
        {
            DatagramPacket packet=new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            socket.receive(packet);
            InetAddress ip=packet.getAddress();
            str=quotes[rand.nextInt(4)];
            sendData=str.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket packet2=new DatagramPacket(sendData,sendData.length,ip,Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
            socket.send(packet2);
            System.out.println("Quote sent to client at address: "+ip);


        }
    }
}

}
```

And here is my Client class.

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.DatagramPacket;
 import java.net.DatagramSocket;
 import java.net.InetAddress;
 import java.net.SocketException;
 import java.net.UnknownHostException;

 public class Client {

 static byte[] sendData;
 static byte[] receiveData;

 static String str="Send a quote please,Mr.Server";
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {  
    sendData=new byte[1024];
    receiveData=new byte[1024];

    DatagramSocket socket=new DatagramSocket();
    sendData=str.getBytes();
    InetAddress address=InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
    DatagramPacket packet=new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, address, 8000);
    socket.send(packet);
    DatagramPacket packet2=new DatagramPacket(receiveData,receiveData.length);
    socket.receive(packet2);
    String str=new String(packet2.getData());
    System.out.println(str);





}

}
```

Comment: UDP is a connection-less protocol so there is no notion of client/server like there is for TCP.

Answer (score 1):

The server is sending the response packet back to the port that the server is listening on. The packet never arrives at the client, but it *does* arrive at the server, which treats it as a client request, and responds to it.

In Server.java, change

```
DatagramPacket packet2 = new DatagramPacket(
    sendData,
    sendData.length,
    ip,
    Integer.parseInt(args[0])    // change this line!
);
```

to

```
DatagramPacket packet2 = new DatagramPacket(
    sendData,
    sendData.length,
    ip,
    packet.getPort()            // into this.
);
```

Comment: Better still, put the reply data into the request packet, which already has its own return address.